# How call a step of waterfall on a particular condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I have a bot made using c# and v4 framework. It always asks user do they want to ask more questions from bot with a yes/no prompt:

[image]

i want that on "clicking on a particular condition of waterfall should be called" otherwise on all other conditions that step of waterfall should skipped and bot should function normally.I am also adding code just for reference.

The code of main dialog

```
public MainDialog(ILogger<MainDialog> logger, IBotServices botServices, UserState userState) : 
     base(nameof(MainDialog))
{ _botServices = botServices;// ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(botServices));
   _logger = logger;
        _userState = userState;
        AddDialog(new ProductIssue($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.fromMain", _botServices, _userState));
        AddDialog(new ProductIssue($"{nameof(Confirm)}.fromConfirm", _botServices, _userState));
        AddDialog(new ProductIssue($"{ nameof(Resolution)}.resolution", _botServices, _userState));
        AddDialog(new PurchaseFlow(_userState));
        AddDialog(new Resolution( _userState));
        AddDialog(new Confirm(_botServices,_userState));
        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.issue"));
        AddDialog(new TextPrompt($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.callDialog"));
        AddDialog(new TextPrompt($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.number", ValidationAsync));


        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.mainFlow", new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            MoblieNumberAsync,
            ChoiceCardStepAsync,
            ShowCardStepAsync,
            CallingDialogsAsync
      }));
        AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));

        InitialDialogId = $"{nameof(MainDialog)}.mainFlow";

    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> MoblieNumberAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        stepContext.Values[UserInfo] = new UserInput();
        var options = new PromptOptions()
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Kindly enter your 10 digit mobile number without any spaces, dashes and country code. We will be sending an OTP later to this number "),
            RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Incorrect mobile number entered. Please only enter the 10 digits of your mobile without any spaces, dashes and country code.")
        };     

        return await stepContext.PromptAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.number", options, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ChoiceCardStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        var userStateAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<UserInput>(nameof(UserInput));
        var userinfo = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, () => new UserInput());
        userinfo.phone_no = (string)stepContext.Result;
        CustomerDetails customerDetails = new CustomerDetails();

        //API-Get Customer Details from CRM
        try
        {
            BotAPIBLL botApiBLL = new BotAPIBLL();
            var response = botApiBLL.GetCustomerDetail(stepContext.Context.Activity.Text); 
            customerDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerDetails>(response);               
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Fetching your details from our systems. This may take a moment"), cancellationToken);

        if (customerDetails.D != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerDetails.D.TelNumber) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerDetails.D.NameFirst))
        {
            DbConnection dbConnection = new DbConnection();
            dbConnection.SaveCutomerInfo(customerDetails);

            userinfo.Name = customerDetails.D.NameFirst;
            var options = new PromptOptions()
            {

                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Welcome " + customerDetails.D.NameFirst + ", How can we serve you ? "),
                RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("That was not a valid choice, please select a option between 1 to 5."),
                Choices = GetChoices(),
                Style = ListStyle.HeroCard
            };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.issue", options, cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            var options = new PromptOptions()
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Welcome Guest_" + userinfo.phone_no + ", How can we serve you ? "),
                RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("That was not a valid choice, please select a option between 1 to 5."),
                Choices = GetChoices(),
                Style = ListStyle.HeroCard
            };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.issue", options, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ShowCardStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var userinfo = (UserInput)stepContext.Values[UserInfo];
        userinfo.choiceselected = ((FoundChoice)stepContext.Result).Value;
        var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        var reply = MessageFactory.Text("");
        var user_choice = ((FoundChoice)stepContext.Result).Value;

        switch (user_choice)
        {
            case "Product issue":
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment3());
                break;
            case "Register Product":
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetHeroCard1().ToAttachment());
                break;
            case "Online Purchase":
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(PurchaseFlow), null, cancellationToken);
            case "Customer Grivance":
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetHeroCard3().ToAttachment());
                break;
            case "Order Status":
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetHeroCard6().ToAttachment());
                break;
            default:
                reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment3());
                reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetHeroCard1().ToAttachment());
                break;
        }
        if (user_choice == "Register Product" || user_choice == "Online Purchase" || user_choice == "Customer Grivance")
        {
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
            Random r = new Random();
            var validationcard = Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment2(_cards[r.Next(_cards.Length)]);
            //var feedbackcard = Cards.CustomerFeedback();
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(validationcard), cancellationToken);
            //await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(feedbackcard), cancellationToken);
            var accessor = _userState.CreateProperty<UserInput>(nameof(UserInput));
            await accessor.SetAsync(stepContext.Context, userinfo, cancellationToken);
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            var options2 = new PromptOptions() { Prompt = reply, RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Retry") };                
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.callDialog", options2, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> CallingDialogsAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {                      
        // First, we use the dispatch model to determine which cognitive service (LUIS or QnA) to use.
        var recognizerResult = await _botServices.Dispatch.RecognizeAsync(stepContext.Context, cancellationToken);

        // Top intent tell us which cognitive service to use.
        var topIntent = recognizerResult.GetTopScoringIntent();

        switch (topIntent.intent)
        {

            case "Mainissue":
                 return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.fromMain", stepContext.Values[UserInfo], cancellationToken);

            case "ConfirmIntent":
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(Confirm), null, cancellationToken);

            case "EndBotIntent":
                return await stepContext.CancelAllDialogsAsync(true, null, null, cancellationToken);

            case "InverterData":
                await ProcessSampleQnAAsync(stepContext, cancellationToken);
                break;
            default:
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"I'm sorry I don't know what you mean."), cancellationToken);
                break;
         }
        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
    }

    private IList<Choice> GetChoices()
    {
        var cardOptions = new List<Choice>()
            {

                new Choice() { Value = "Product issue", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "adaptive" } },
                new Choice() { Value = "Register Product", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "hero" } },
                new Choice() { Value = "Online Purchase", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "hero" } },
                new Choice() { Value = "Customer Grivance", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "hero" } },
                new Choice() { Value = "Order Status", Synonyms = new List<string>() { "hero" } }
            };

        return cardOptions;
    }

    private Task<bool> ValidationAsync(PromptValidatorContext<string> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string value = (string)promptContext.Context.Activity.Text;
        if (Regex.IsMatch(value, "^[0-9]{10}$"))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
        else
        {
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessSampleQnAAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("ProcessSampleQnAAsync");

        var results = await _botServices.SampleQnA.GetAnswersAsync(stepContext.Context);
        if (results.Any())
        {
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(results.First().Answer), cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Sorry, could not find an answer in the Q and A system."), cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You start by saying you have a confirm prompt but it's unclear what that has to do with the rest of your question where you mention waterfall steps and conditions. Are you saying you want to know how to skip a waterfall step? Are you saying you want to jump backwards to a particular step in the current waterfall? Are you saying the confirm prompt is a step you want to skip? Are you saying the confirm is the "particular condition" that you want to use? Linking to docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the step by evaluating the condition and calling `NextAsync`, like this:

```
if (condition)
{
    await stepContext.NextAsync(stepContext.Result, cancellationToken);
}

// otherwise process this step
```

The `NextAsync` immediately passes control to the next step with whatever you used as the 1st parameter. In this case, I used `stepContext.Result`, which is the result of the previous step that will be passed to the next step.

Comment: Thanks @joe for your help